# android - inflate and attach a custom layout on list item during swip gesture

Tags: android, listview

I have a list view with custom list row layout. I want to implement a functionality in which the user swipes the list item to the right and sees another layout showing some more information on the row. Here is a figure about what I mean:

[image: item row being swipped]
<sub>(source: [persiangig.com](http://mahdi-cpp.persiangig.com/row.jpg))</sub>

I have already implemented the swipe gesture on items, but I haven't figured out on how to inflate and attach another layout on the selected item which contains some more details like the contact's phone number, etc.

Any suggestion and workaround is appreciated

Thanks

Mahdi

Comment: Design your layout for the row with two Linearlayouts horizontally(left, righr). One for the main view(right) and another for the number view(left). set visiblity of the left one to gone. And use android:animateLayoutChanges="true" in the parent layout. And set Visibility of the left layout to visible when the user swipes.

Comment: Im afraid it's not working correctly.

Comment: I have made both layouts visible but when I swipe a list row I can see that both layouts are being swipped.

Comment: first set the visibility of the number layout to gone. Make visible it when swipe left to right, and set gone when the user swipes right to left..

Answer (score 0):

Use this one..

```
<LinearLayout
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true" 
     >//parent

       <LinearLayout
         android:visibility = "gone">
        //number layout
       </LinearLayout>

       <LinearLayout>
       //actual layout
       </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try to do it using a different approach:
Each item in the list can have both the main and additional layout from the start (you don't have to add them dynamically).

For example, you can create a single row with the following layout:

```
Row 
  --> Layout B
  --> Layout A
```

Where layout A (main row view) is directly above Row B (row information view). Then, when a user makes a swipe on the row you can move only Layout A with the swipe, which will reveal Layout B which is underneath.
This is the basic idea, needless to say that you will have to deal with making the view behave as you want (for example, close the row when you click on it).

Another option, which suits the example you have the picture above is making each row parent to be HorizontalScrollView and put both layouts side by side. The starting position should be as such that the first item (in your case - the number) is invisible (outside the view). Then Scrolling right will reveal it.

If you want it to appear with animation, you can implement it your own (basing on the gesture) or play with the visibility of the additional view and use `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` in the parent as suggested.

Comment: Your answer is quite similar to @Sripthi but it doesn't work as I need. Swipping the list row moves both layouts not only the front one.

Comment: See my edit, it provides two ways to achieve what you wanted.